# How to use JWT tokens with WCF and WIF?

Tags: wcf, wif, jwt, identityserver3

### General notes

We're using [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) and have been very happy with it so far.
We've gotten to secure MVC and ASP.NET Web API applications very easily with the help of both MS and Thinktecture OWIN middlewares.

The client we're working for still has a lot of SOAP WCF services, and this is where we're getting stuck.

### The Setup

I'm not gonna lie, I'm far from being experienced with WCF, I've only used it for very basic scenarios - understand basicHttpBinding, no transport nor message security.

This is what I want to achieve:

- A client gets a JWT access token from IdentityServer
- Somehow the token ends up in the SOAP message headers
- WCF reads and validates the token
- WCF inspects the claims and performs authorization based on some criterion

I can't get the third step working.

#### The server setup

- I'm using a `ws2007FederationHttpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential` security mode. The message contains a `BearerKey` and the token is of type `urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt`
- The service uses the WIF identity pipeline, in which I added the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` from the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` NuGet package

#### The client setup

- The JWT token issued by the STS is wrapped in a `BinarySecurityToken` XML element, itself wrapped in a `GenericXmlSecurityElement`
- This token is used as a parameter of the `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` of the `ChannelFactory`

#### What happens

The token is found in the SOAP header and passed on to the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.
But then an exception is thrown:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Message security verification failed. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[] chars)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetString(Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.StringHandle.GetString()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadEndElement()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message&amp;amp; message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp;amp; message, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

After JustDecompiling, it looks like there's an error when further reading the XML elements in the SOAP header. What's strange is that the token is the last element. Here's what the whole message looks like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService/GetListOfStrings</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:5c22d4e2-f9b8-451a-b4ca-a844f41f7231</a:MessageID>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="554fc496-7c47-4063-9539-d25606f186b0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">1213dcd7-55b7-4153-8a6d-92e0922f76dd</ActivityId>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo90CpMlUwLBOmEPkZ5C8fRQAAAAAVWkkf2rJS0qImBv+Yx1recUXdbBLjThDkAMkwfW3/2AACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://localhost.fiddler:44322/Service.svc</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2015-05-21T06:41:45.362Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2015-05-21T06:46:45.362Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><!-- Removed --></wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetListOfStrings xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Doesn't look like there's something malformed or anything. From the stack trace, the exception must be thrown when reading the `</o:Security>` end element since the token was properly read and handled.

### Repro

I forked the [samples repo](https://github.com/mderriey/IdentityServer3.Samples) so you can have a look if you feel like it.
Here are the relevant projets:

- `SelfHost (Minimal)` in the `sources` folder. This is the STS
- In the `Clients` solution, the WCF service is in the `APIs` folder
- In the `Clients` solution, the WCF client is the `Console Client Credentials With Wcf` project

Best way to fire it up is to start the STS first, then `Right click -> Debug -> Start new instance` on the WCF service, then the same on the WCF client.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I didn't get to solve this problem but Dominick Baier, one of the developers of IdentityServer, found a workaround.
He thinks the exception comes from a bug in WCF or an incompatibility between WCF and the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`. Since he considers WCF *done*, he doesn't expect someone to take a look at it.

His solution is to wrap the JWT token in a SAML token. Then, by subclassing `SamlSecurityTokenHandler`, get it back and validate it against an instance of `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.

Here are the links:

- [Dominick's blog post](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/)
- [Samples repo on GitHub where he put the code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/dev)
- [Specific commit on GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/commit/dd01c56fca23449a7f1f2dfda81f148de65efbe2)

Everybody have fun, now :-)