# Using Microsoft Jwt handler with symmetric signing key using Oauth 2 resource owner flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, wif, jwt, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model

I'm trying to use an OAuth 2 Resource Owner Flow to authorize a mobile client against my Web Api services.  I'm using Thinktecture IdentityServer to issue the jwt token with a symmetric signing key.

On the client side I'm using Thinktecture IdentityModel to help setup the token validation.  My WebApiConfig looks like this:

```cs
        var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var mapping = new AuthenticationOptionMapping
        {
            // where to look for credentials
            Options = AuthenticationOptions.ForAuthorizationHeader("bearer"),

            // how to validate them
            TokenHandler = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection { jwtSecurityTokenHandler },

            // which hint to give back if not successful
            Scheme = AuthenticationScheme.SchemeOnly("bearer")
        };
        var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration(){RequireSsl = false};
        authConfig.AddMapping(mapping);
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authConfig));
```

In my IdentityModel.config I have the following:

```xml
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration>
<claimsAuthorizationManager type="PresentationHost.Claims.MobileClaimsAuthorizationManager, PresentationHost"/>
<audienceUris>
  <add value="http://localhost:22674/" />
</audienceUris>

<securityTokenHandlers>
  <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" />
</securityTokenHandlers>

<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
  <authority name="http://identityserver.v2.thinktecture.com/trust/auth">
    <keys>
      <add symmetricKey="tVNRmpweBgz3xeWvSXrSwLIE3DrxJ3aawgNxZKC1Od0"/>
    </keys>
    <validIssuers>
      <add name="http://identityserver.v2.thinktecture.com/trust/auth" />
    </validIssuers>
  </authority>
</issuerNameRegistry>

<issuerTokenResolver type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeyIssuerTokenResolver, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"/>
  <securityKey symmetricKey="tVNRmpweBgz3xeWvSXrSwLIE3DrxJ3aawgNxZKC1Od0" name="http://identityserver.v2.thinktecture.com/trust/auth" />


<!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
<certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
```

Taken mostly from this link on http://leastprivilege.com/2013/07/16/identityserver-using-ws-federation-with-jwt-tokens-and-symmetric-signatures/  which I found via this Stack Overflow post: [How to configure MIcrosoft JWT with symmetric key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735753/how-to-configure-microsoft-jwt-with-symmetric-key)

I attempted to use the derived class as found in that post, but when I attempted to run this line:

```cs
var resolver = (NamedKeyIssuerTokenResolver)this.Configuration.IssuerTokenResolver;
```

I get an InvalidCastException because the IssuerTokenResolver is of type X509CertificateStoreResolver and not of type NamedKeyIssuerTokenResolver.

It appears I'm still missing something from my configuration or code to get the correct TokenResolver configured.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use my jwt Config Extension methods?

Comment: @leastprivilege Honestly, because I didn't know about them.  I'm looking at them now and they could be a big help.  I did get the jwt handler working by switching to x509 certs instead of symmetric signing keys and sub classing the JwtSecurityTokenHandler class to properly setup the TokenValidationParameters.                                               I will take a look at using your methods to further refine my solution.  Thanks.